# How to use TypeScript for next.js Server?

Tags: typescript, next.js

In the latest release of next.js the [TypeScript support](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-typescript) has been added, but it works only for the Browser.

Is there a way to use TypeScript on the server too? I.e. use `server.ts` instead of `server.js`?

One way I can thing of is to tell the IDE to generate `js` file for every `ts` file in the project, but maybe there's a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think it works for everything but the custom server file. The reason is that webpack transpiles the typescript to js and webpack itself is kicked off by server.js.

using a combination of [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) and [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) would do the workaround:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon --watch 'server.ts' --exec 'ts-node' server.ts"
}
```